# combining IF and AND statement not working in excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2007

I am trying to calculate the percentage, here the rules are as follows:
01. Employees working in IT department for more than 10 years will get 7% and rest of the IT guys will get 6.5%
02. And for rest of the departments, we have different percentages

Here `H` column represents various departments and `F` is working experience and in column `I` we're getting the main value from which we have to calculate the percentages. 
    Here's what I tried

```
=IF(AND(H5="IT",F5<10),I5*6.5%,I5*7%,IF(H5="PRODUCTION",I5*9%,IF(H5="MARKETING",I5*6%,IF(H5="LAW",I5*6%,IF(H5="HR",I5*9.36%)))))
```

This is showing `You've entered too many arguments`

Answer (score 2):

Your first If statement, really had one too many argument.

```
=IF(AND(H5="IT",F5<10),I5*6.5%,IF(H5="PRODUCTION",I5*9%,IF(H5="MARKETING",I5*6%,IF(H5="LAW",I5*6%,IF(H5="HR",I5*9.36%,I5*7%)))))
```

Since each new `if` is nested as the FALSE eventuality. Look at the end for that 7%.

**Edit:**
My bad(reading your comment made me realize), there are two error in your formula.
One has been discussed, the second is how you nested those IT percentage.
`=IF(AND(H5="IT",F5>=10),I5*7%,IF(AND(H5="IT",F5<10),I5*6.5%,IF(H5="PRODUCTION",I5*9%,IF(H5="MARKETING",I5*6%,IF(H5="LAW",I5*6%,IF(H5="HR",I5*9.36%,""))))))`

In this version I added another `IF` statement. We could have avoided it by defining either one of the IT's rate as the `ELSE` result same as my initial answer. Now all predictable eventuality have their own TRUE match. An unexpected value will return an empty string. Maybe you want it to be 0 instead...

Answer (score 1):

```
(1) IF(AND(...))= conditions
(2) I5 * 6.5% = value if true 
(3) I5 * 7% = value if false
```

Therefore, you already indicate value if false and another if statement is not allowed. I would remove (3) and put it to the very end of your formula. As such, once none of the previous conditions are met, it will automatically take on the value of 7%.

Comment: I have tried, it's working as it should but only it's not checking for the `AND` condition. this is what I tried `=IF(IF(H31="PRODUCTION",I31*9%,IF(H31="MARKETING",I31*6%,IF(H31="LAW",I31*6%,IF(H31="HR",I31*9.36%))))*AND(H31="IT",F31<30),I31*6.5%,I31*7%)`